# Экспорт данных о заказах с сайта в 1с

Tags: modx, minishop2, php, 1с

Добрый день, всем! Вопрос такой ко всем, кто работал с компонентом mSklad. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как экспорт данных о совершенных заказов с сайта Modx в 1с. Если в первоначальном варианте компонента, эту проблему удалось решить, то сейчас, после обновления, компонент mSklad опять делает отказ в обслуживании, не хочет передавать данные. Анализ лога в 1с показывает следующую ошибку:

```
Интерактивный обмен
27.11.2014 17:33:19 Запуск загрузки заказов
Обработано: 0
Загружено: 0
Пропущено: 0
Обновлено: 0
Создано: 0
27.11.2014 17:33:20 Завершена загрузка заказов
Дополнительная информация: Не удалось прочитать данные, загруженные с сервера.
```

С разработчиком связывался, он хранил молчание по этому поводу, потом ссылался на то, что некоторые данные заказов не связаны с реальными пользователями, так как они были уже удалены. После удаления таких «битых» заказов ситуация не изменилась никак.

Насколько я понял формируются xml-отчеты в папке assets/components/msklad/1c_temp, но там не обнаружил своих заказов получаемых с сайта. Изучая дальше, я нашел файлы отвечающие за формирование этих отчетов-документов, которые потом передаются в 1с-документ. Этот файл лежит по следующему пути: core/msklad/model/msklad/mskladhandler.class.php

Там в публичной функции query видно, что идет формирование документа, но непонятно почему туда попадают только документы у которых стоит статус «В обработке». Где это можно отключить? Буду признателен за помощь.

И второй вопрос, изучая документацию по mSklad заметил, такую опцию в настройках компонента:

[image]

Где она реально применяется? В админке пытался переключить вручную статус заказа на заказ в обработке, но не получилось. В настройках мишишопа такая настройка тоже есть:

[image]

Но как переключить в такой режим заказ непонятно. Спасибо, если кто прочитал мой, возможно, утомительный вопрос. Написал просто о наболевшем).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день всем!

Да, [@Expert](/users/6/expert), ответить я просто обязан на свой вопрос, так как проблему решил.

После тщательного умозрительного анализа проблемы, я перешел к практическим действиям и нашел файл в компоненте mSklad, который отвечает за формирование гипертекстового документа. Он находится, по пути, `\core\components\model\msklad\mskladhandler.class.php`. На 106 строке находится публичная функция query, в которой идет формирование документа, который по http протоколу принимается в 1c. В 1с, кстати, тоже нашел обработку, отвечающую за это.

Проблема решается одним из двух путей: либо в прописании в файле mskladhandler.class.php добавления данных ИНН, если в 1с при соединении данных с сайтам будут передаваться контрагенты по "ИНН+КПП", либо второй вариант - переключение в 1с в режим идентификации контрагентов по "Наименованию". Важно следить за тем, чтобы товары присутствовали в магазине (которые изначально опять же были экспортированы из 1с в магазин), которые были оформлены в заказах, так как при их отсутствии 1с ругается на пустые наименования товаров и отказывается добавлять в контрагенты заказы покупок в магазине.

Что касается нюанса по статусу заказов "В обработке" по `msklad_order_access_id`, то этот статус присваивается только тем заказам, которые уже были переданы в 1с. Устанавливается это значение программно в скриптах компонента mSklad, вручную нельзя задавать такой статус заказам.

Изложил ответ, может, немного сумбурно и кратко, но постарался пояснить суть проблемы в вопросе и ответить на него в данном ответе. Спасибо всем за внимание.